# div 100% in table-cell

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I wrote this code and I don't have idea why it doesn't work 100% in `#sidebar` (`display: table-cell`).

This is my code CSS:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">

body { margin: 0 auto; width: 800px; }

#wrapper{
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden; /* clearance */
}

#panel1, #panel2{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width:400px;
}

#panel1{ background-color: blue; }

#panel2{ background-color: grey; }



#sidebar, #content{ float:left; }

#sidebar{
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
}

</style>
</head>
```

And HTML code :

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper"> 

        <div id="panel1"> 
            <div id="sidebar">menu</div>

            <div id="content">
                <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>end
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="panel2"><br/></div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want the sidebar height to be 100% of the div containing it (in this case it is panel1)

The reason your sidebar is not displaying the way that you want it too is because you do not have a height set for the div that is holding the menu (in your code this would be the 'panel1' div).

To fix this issue just set a height for the container ('panel1') and your sidebar will adjust accordingly.

CSS

```
#panel1 { 
     background-color: blue;
     height: 600px; /* You can set this height to whatever size you prefer */
     }
```

[You can view it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/bambee/xFLku/1/)

Comment: Height #panel1, #panel2 and #content (here ajax) change every moment, because here is used ajax. The're notyfications and forms etc.
Earlier i used jQuery for change height but i don't want to use it again.

Comment: ##### I HAVE ANSWER BUT I CAN'T ADD ####
**** ANSWER :
Heh, i just had to add height: 100%; for #panel1, #panel2 :)
And now it's working.
Thank You for trying to help me. You're fast :)

Comment: @Jeremy. Don't forget to select this answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying for equal height columns?  If so, please take a look here:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/08/equal-height-columns-using-borders-and-negative-margins-with-css/

There are several other articles and tricks of how to achieve this, simply google "equal height columns in html/css"

Comment: I have answer in comment [UP POST by bambee] :)

Comment: That answer will work, however if you have any content that extends beyond the 600px height of the container div it will no longer be equal height.

Comment: No, i haven't 600px anywhere. Only i add height: 100%; for #panel1 and #panel2. Your answer is too interesting.

Comment: The first answer calls you to put a constraint on your container div's height (#panel1) of 600px (or whatever size, as she stated).  The problem is, if you have content that ever needs more vertical space than what you are allotting in the container div (600px for example), then you will no longer have the matching div height for both the right and left.  The solution is not expandable depending on content that may exceed that area.  Once you need more than 600px of vertical space, you are back to where you started.

Comment: Ok, but i don't add 600px. I have own answer, but i can't add.
Look, here isn't 600px, only i add 100% to two div and all work:
http://jsbin.com/alulav/1/

Comment: Strange, same code you have in fiddle does not allow for "#sidebar" to extend.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/ScxvW/1/ Oh well, good luck!

Comment: It work on localhost and other online html/css. I think it's okey. Thanks :)